# Receiving empty response from servlet

Tags: javascript, ajax, tomcat, servlets

I have an ajax web application requesting data to servlet deployed on Tomcat 5.5. I am connecting to Tomcat using HTTPS protocol.

I wrote one servlet which is called from ajax page and it responds in the form of XML as `<response></response>`. But sometimes, I receive response as empty, nothing in it, just blank (and I confess that I am not sending any blank response in any way).

I investigated Tomcat access logs and it shows me following entry:

```
<Time> \MyServlet HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Which means that my request was OK, fulfilled and response bytes are zero as `-`.

I did not find any error/exception in Tomcat logs as well.

I have no idea from where this empty response comes as my server side logs does not contain any detail for this request.

When I tried to debug the servlet by adding some logging statements, those statements are not even getting printed. I am assuming that service method is not even executed.

Is this due to Tomcat?

is there specific number of threads/request that Tomcat 5.5 can handle?

Comment: Not sure how anyone can help with the info provided.

Comment: What else info is missing ?
what should i can provide ?

Comment: Anything. Basically you're saying your car doesn't run, and expecting me to diagnose it from here. At this point it could be *anything*.